# How do you disconnect a tv satellite from the roof?

Tags: cable-management

We recently had the roof replaced. The roofers discarded the old satellite dish portion left from the previous owners but the cable to the dish was left dangling from the roof with some kind of heavy attachment piece at the end (it looks like a trailer hitch), banging the side of the house.  How do we remove it safely?  Is it still energized?

Answer (score 1):

If the piece dangling from the wire looks like this, [image]

then you should be able to unscrew the cable from it ( connector on the left end of picture). Or,if the cable is not connected to a receiver in the house, it should have no power to it and you can cut it off with a pair of pliers.

Comment: good interpretation of "looks like trailer hitch", spot on with answer too.